# How to enumerize and split csv column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

We have a CSV. It has a fixed (repeating) set of strings in a column. Say column is called "Type" and values are `[A, B, B, C]`. I want to get several new columns equal to the number of unique column values with 0 or 1 in them. like this:

```
Type Type_1 Type_2 Type_3
A      1      0      0
B      0      1      0
B      0      1      0
C      0      0      1
```

How to turn a column into a set of 0\1 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `str.get_dummies`

```
df.Type.str.get_dummies()
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
```

Update

```
df=df.join(df.pop('Type').str.get_dummies())
```

Comment: And how one can update df replacing original column with generated ones?